# Is there a version of chromedriver matching to Chrome version 96.0.4664.110?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get the right chromedriver version for me so I can learn selenium in google, but I can't find a downloadable 96.0.4664.110 version of it. Do they just flat out not have it? You would think the latest version would be included in something as big as that. If it's just not there, could I downgrade my google version somehow?

Comment: From https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads, at the very top of the page - "*If you are using Chrome version 96, please download ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45*".

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are using the latest *Google Chrome Version **96.0.4664.110*** and you may not find a matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) with identical [major and minor versions](https://www.akeeba.com/how-do-version-numbers-work.html).

However, a matching ***major*** version can cater to your needs. So you can download and use [ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) and safely avoid the risk of downgrading the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) version.

Comment: I think mattdmo got this in the comments first.

Comment: When I downloaded it, windows defender immediately quarantined a "severe trojan threat". What's going on?

Comment: @DiscoveringCreation okay :) be brave enough to ask windows defender to allow downloads from this site. However, a lot many developers including me have to believe that site data mines actively ;)